# java transaction shouldnot rollback all records(in case of failures)

Tags: java, sql, database, spring, transactions

In my application, I am doing the following

```
1. Getting 25 records from the DB.
2. Update every 10 records
   Here I have a loop to update every 10 records.so there will be 3 loops.
   For each loop I need to have a new transaction.(so that only  the 10 record will rollback and not all the records will rollback)   
//line 1  
    getRecords();//25 records from DB  //line 2  
    For(Records r: loop) {  //line 3  
    add 10 records;  //line 4  
    call update method(object with 10 records)   //line 5  
}
  //line 6  
updateRecords()//this method updates the 10 records\\line 7
```

Here I think  I need to use `@Transaction(REQUIRED)` at line 6.
so that only  the 10 records will rollback and not all the records will rollback.

Can anyone please confirm if this is the correct approach?

Comment: What framework/tools are you using to update your tables?

Comment: I am calling a dao class. that dao class return(throws) exception whenever something fails. I dont know what framework the dao implements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Transaction(REQUIRED) will continue the existing transaction if one exists and will create a transaction if no transaction exists. I think in your case you can use @Transaction(REQUIRES_NEW) which will create a new transaction always.

In case of EJB transactions [this](http://www.javabeat.net/managing-transactions-in-ejb-3-0/) explains various transaction attributes.